# how to declare z in accordion

Tags: android

http://android-apps-creater.blogspot.in/2013/12/how-to-implement-accordian-in-android.html
how to declare Z in this?????

Comment: Your tutorial seems to be vagueness...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `z array` is supposed to tell if a view is expanded or not. That being said, we have to store a value for each layout, so having 8 layouts, the array will have 8 values. To declare it use the following `int z[] = new int[8];`, but as @MalteseFalcon said, your tutorial is not the best.